# Setting Input Button Background Image Not Working

Tags: html, css, image, background

I'm trying to set an input button's image in a jsp. My code for the button is like so:

```
<input type="button" name="Unassign" class="btnUnassignHandlerRule" style="width:50px;" />
//setting width inline because it's not working in the CSS
```

And the CSS code is like so:

```
.btnUnassignHandlerRule{
   background: url(../Images/leftarrow.png) no-repeat;
   height: 50px;
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```

My file hierarchy looks like this:

jsp: **web/WEB-INF/jsp/myJspPage.jsp**

Image: **web/Images/leftarrow.png**

Please let me know if my code if correct and if my paths are correct as well? Otherwise I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Your code works, check if the directory ../Images/leftarrow.png exists

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g5zKz/

Could you show the path to the css File ? So we can look if your in the wrong path !

Comment: Thanks for the help, the path the CSS file is correct as other CSS functions work in the jsp page. Working with liferay so the path the CSS is a complicated matter, nevertheless it's the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Change `../Images/leftarrow.png` to `../../Images/leftarrow.png` if the page and image URLs are as described. By the way, in my test, `width: 50px` works fine even when placed in the same CSS rule as the other settings.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll check if it works just now. I'm working with portlets in liferay portal. It's quite funny, liferay messes around with ones CSS files, that's why I had to resort to the inline width setting.

Comment: Okay that's not working :-( Is there a way to just do this inline as well?

Comment: If the background setting does not work, check out the URLs again. You can also test whether a content image shows when using the URL: `<imr src="../../Images/leftarrow.png" alt="???">`. Regarding inline CSS, you can of course place all the declarations inside your `style` attribute, but if they don’t work when in a `style` element, the question arises whether there is something in the *other* CSS settings for the page that overrides them.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this css.

```
input.btnUnassignHandlerRule{
   background: url(../Images/leftarrow.png) no-repeat;
   height: 50px;
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```